# cross compile sh script to bin for enigma2 (mips) OpenEmbedded

Tags: cross-compiling, sh, mips32, codesourcery, enigma2

I have a dreambox satellite receiver which operates with Enigma2 OpenEmbedded. So MIPS architecture.
I want to cross compile at my Ubuntu PC a .sh file to an Enigma2 binary file.

I installed codesourcery cross compile toolchain for mips32 architecture on my Ubuntu PC.

Toolchain info:

```
/mips-compiler/mips-linux-gnu-gcc -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/mips-compiler/mips-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/root/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_MIPS_GNU_Linux/bin/../libexec/gcc/mips-linux-gnu/4.7.3/lto-wrapper
Target: mips-linux-gnu
Configured with: /scratch/cmoore/2013.05-36-mips-linux-lite/src/gcc-4.7-2013.05/configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=mips-linux-gnu --enable-threads --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-arch-32=mips32r2 --with-arch-64=mips64r2 --with-float=hard --with-mips-plt --enable-extra-sgxxlite-multilibs --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-specs='%{save-temps: -fverbose-asm} -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MAJ__=2013 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MIN__=5 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_REV__=36 %{O2:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}} %{O*:%{O|O0|O1|O2|Os:;:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}}}' --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared --enable-lto --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-pkgversion='Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-36' --with-bugurl=https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/ --disable-nls --prefix=/opt/codesourcery --with-sysroot=/opt/codesourcery/mips-linux-gnu/libc --with-build-sysroot=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-36-mips-linux-lite/install/mips-linux-gnu/libc --with-gmp=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-36-mips-linux-lite/obj/pkg-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-mpfr=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-36-mips-linux-lite/obj/pkg-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-mpc=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-36-mips-linux-lite/obj/pkg-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-ppl=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-36-mips-linux-lite/obj/pkg-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-cloog=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-36-mips-linux-lite/obj/pkg-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-libelf=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-36-mips-linux-lite/obj/pkg-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-36-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --disable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-poison-system-directories --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-36-mips-linux-lite/install/mips-linux-gnu/bin --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-36-mips-linux-lite/install/mips-linux-gnu/bin
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-36)
```

I used SHC to convert the .sh file to a .c file
Then I cross compiled that c file to a mips binary with the command:

```
/mips-compiler/mips-linux-gnu-gcc -mips32 -o test.bin test.sh.x.c
```

No errors seen (I was so happy, but unfortunately (see below)).
Then copied the bin file to my enigma2 box and tried to execute it...

When I ran the output binary on the MIPS box I see this:

```
./test.bin: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

So obviously I forgot something in the cross compile command, but what?

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I work for CodeSourcery/Mentor Graphics.)

Using a slightly newer version of the same toolchain, here are my results when run from an Ubuntu 12.04 host system.  First, the version:

```
 lite@sourcerydemo:~$ /home/lite/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_MIPS_GNU_Linux/bin/mips-linux-gnu-gcc -v
 Using built-in specs.
 COLLECT_GCC=/home/lite/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_MIPS_GNU_Linux/bin/mips-linux-gnu-gcc
 COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/lite/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_MIPS_GNU_Linux/bin/../libexec/gcc/mips-linux-gnu/4.7.3/lto-wrapper
 Target: mips-linux-gnu
 Configured with: /scratch/cmoore/2013.05-mips-linux/src/gcc-4.7-2013.05/configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=mips-linux-gnu --enable-threads --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-arch-32=mips32r2 --with-arch-64=mips64r2 --with-float=hard --with-mips-plt --enable-extra-sgxxlite-multilibs --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-specs='%{save-temps: -fverbose-asm} -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MAJ__=2013 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MIN__=5 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_REV__=66 %{O2:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}} %{O*:%{O|O0|O1|O2|Os:;:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}}}' --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared --enable-lto --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-pkgversion='Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-66' --with-bugurl=https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/ --disable-nls --prefix=/opt/codesourcery --with-sysroot=/opt/codesourcery/mips-linux-gnu/libc --with-build-sysroot=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-mips-linux/install/mips-linux-gnu/libc --with-gmp=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-mips-linux/obj/pkg-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-mpfr=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-mips-linux/obj/pkg-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-mpc=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-mips-linux/obj/pkg-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-ppl=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-mips-linux/obj/pkg-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-cloog=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-mips-linux/obj/pkg-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-libelf=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-mips-linux/obj/pkg-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu/mips-2013.05-66-mips-linux-gnu.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-poison-system-directories --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-mips-linux/install/mips-linux-gnu/bin --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/cmoore/2013.05-mips-linux/install/mips-linux-gnu/bin SED=sed
 Thread model: posix
 gcc version 4.7.3 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-66)
```

Then code, build and the output of the file command to show more info about the executable produced:

```
 lite@sourcerydemo:~$ /home/lite/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_MIPS_GNU_Linux/bin/mips-linux-gnu-gcc --version
 mips-linux-gnu-gcc (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-66) 4.7.3
 Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
 warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

 lite@sourcerydemo:~$ cat hello.c
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   printf("hello world!\n");
 }
 lite@sourcerydemo:~$ /home/lite/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_MIPS_GNU_Linux/bin/mips-linux-gnu-gcc -mips32 hello.c -o hello
 lite@sourcerydemo:~$ file hello
 hello: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0x70401, not stripped
```

What is the output of the file command on the binary you produce?

Comment: Thanks Ricardo for replying. Appreciate your help so much.
When I compare what you wrote with what I did, it seems to be the same. So that all must be ok.

You asked for the output of the binary file command. Do you mean the same output as you wrote in your reply of 'cat hello.c'? If so, that would be a very very large output coz I have a long shell script. And that shell script itself is ok, because when I do not cross compile it but just compile it with gcc for my Ubuntu machine it is running perfectly.

Comment: Hello ni_hao. I meant the `file` command, usually located in `/usr/bin/file` on Ubuntu systems, as shown in the second to last last line in the quoted output above. You can see that `file` tells me that the `hello` file I produced is a 32-bit executable for a MIPS Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to compile a shell script to C in order to run it. Just copy the original script to your receiver and run it directly.